# Question on separability of a measure

Tags: measure-theory, boolean-algebras, lebesgue-measure

Following this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/27494/separable-sigma-algebra-equivalence-of-two-definitions) this question come to mind.

Consider a measured σ-algebra $(S,\mu)$ . Assume that μ is normalized to have total weight 1, and that S is complete (contains all subsets of null sets).

> $(S,\mu)$ is *separable* if it has a countable subset $\Gamma$ that is not only dense w.r.t. $\rho$ but also has the property that for every $A\in S$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $B\in \Gamma$ such that $\mu(B\Delta  A) < \epsilon$; we denote this property by **(S)**
>
> $(S,\mu)$ is *one-sided separable* if it has a countable subset $\Gamma$ that is not only dense w.r.t. $\rho$ but also has the property that for every $A\in S$ and $\epsilon>0$ there exists $B\in \Gamma$ such that $A\subset B$ and $\mu(B\setminus A) < \epsilon$; we denote this property by **(S1)**

@Vaughn Climenhaga stated that if $\mu$ is non-atomic (in the sense of measure), then this two definitions are equivalent.

> Clearly **S1$\implies$ S**, but I am asking how they are equivalent ?? How **S1** will be satisfied when $S=L$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets in $[0,1]$. I even have a doubt that $L/N$, where $N$ is the set of all nulls, will satisfy **S1**!

Comment: Please change the title - it should clarify what the problem is about. Also, don't use double $?$s. It's unprofessional.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar, thanks for your note.

Comment: There seems to be a copy-paste error in the statement of property (S).  Also, you have not defined $\rho$.

Comment: @Algernon I am aware of it, but here is $\rho(A,B) = \mu(A\bigtriangleup B)$, which is also mentioned by only $\mu(A\bigtriangleup B)$. This is a separable in the sense of Kakutani.

Comment: What am I missing? If $A\subset B$, then $\mu(B\setminus A)=\mu(A\bigtriangleup B)$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Oh thanks for letting me know, I have to remove $A\subset B$ from the first definition!

Comment: I think what's clear is the other implication S1$\Rightarrow$S.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I am really in debt with you for these corrections. I wasn't a good reviewer.

Comment: As Nik Weaver's answer below makes clear, my assertion on that other question was nonsense.  I apologize for the confusion caused by my carelessness; I hope everything is straightened out now.  (I just noticed this question quite recently and was somewhat chagrined at how long my wrong answer has been sitting there...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, S1 holds if and only if the measure is a countable sum of atoms (I will understand the inclusion in the weak sense, i.e., ignoring sets of measure $0$, which makes the part directly relevant to the original question harder, but any other consistent interpretation will lead to the same proof and conclusion after tweaking the definition of an atom in an appropriate way).

One direction is obvious: if $A_j$ are (disjoint) atoms and $C$ is the remaining part of the space, then the countable family of sets $B=C\cup(\cup_{j\in J}A_j)$ where $J$ runs over all cofinite subsets of $\mathbb N$ has the required property.

On the other hand, if there is a non-atomic part $E$ with $\mu(E)=m>0$  and $\Gamma$ is any countable subset of $S$, then we can enumerate all sets $B_j\in\Gamma$ with $\mu(E\setminus B_j)>0$. Since $E$ is non-atomic, we can choose $U_j\subset E\setminus B_j$ with $0<\mu(U_j)<2^{-j-1}m$. Put $U=\cup_j U_j$. Then no $B_j$ is of any use for approximating $U$, but if $B\in\Gamma$ essentially contains $E$, then $\mu(B\setminus U)\ge \mu(E)-\mu(U)\ge m-\frac m2=\frac m2$, so there is a fixed positive lower limit for the approximation error in this case as well.

Comment: Can anybody explain why the spaces after some math. formulae are suppressed or/and edit the text to restore them?

Comment: I notice nothing wrong with the rendering of the math. Can you describe the issue you are seeing more precisely? Is it an obvious effect?

Comment: Now it is fine on my screen too, but at the moment of submission the plain text after several formulae was glued without a space (like "$a+b$is a sum") and the effect persisted after reloading the page in FF and changing to Chrome.

Comment: @Rina Shora I'll happily do it if you explain what exactly gives you trouble: in the case you mention $E=[0,1]$ and the main property I use is that any set of positive Lebesgue measure contains a subset of arbitrarily small but still positive measure.

Comment: @Rina Shora The first thing to do is to write the inclusion and to arrange the quantifiers in the negation in the right order. Until then, what you said, indeed, has little to do with what I proved.

Comment: @Rina Shora OK, the right formulation of the negation (for the Lebesgue case) is: "For every countable family $\Gamma$ of measurable sets, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ and a measurable set $U$ such that for every $B\in\Gamma$ either $\mu(U\setminus B)>0$, or $\mu(B\setminus U)>\varepsilon$. Is it clear why this refutes S1? If so, is it clear how $U$ was constructed given $\Gamma$? (the choice of $\varepsilon$ was universal, but the choice of $U$, obviously, depended on $\Gamma$).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a mistake in Vaughn Climenhaga's answer to that other question. Surely he is thinking of the fact that the every measurable subset of $[0,1]$ is approximated from without by an open subset.

To see that (S1) fails for $[0,1]$, let $\Gamma = \{A_1, A_2, \ldots\}$ be any countable family of measurable subsets of $[0,1]$. For each $n$ such that $A_n$ is not the entire interval $[0,1]$, choose $x_n \in [0,1]\setminus A_n$. Then the set of these $x_n$ is countable, hence it has measure zero, but it is not contained in any $A_n$ except those, if any, which equal $[0,1]$. So it is not approximated from the outside in measure by sets in $\Gamma$.

Comment: Since $A^*$ has measure zero, it follows that $\mu(A^*\triangle B) = \mu(B)$ for any measurable set $B$. So as long as $\Gamma$ contains sets of arbitrarily small measure, we will be able to achieve $\mu(A^*\triangle A_i) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Try asking on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Oh dear -- I've just seen this question and answer quite recently and realized that I was much too hasty in my assertions on that other question.  Thanks for pointing this out -- I've fixed my answer there (http://mathoverflow.net/q/27494/5701) and have written a blog post at https://vaughnclimenhaga.wordpress.com/2015/10/22/lebesgue-probability-spaces-part-i/ that clarifies my understanding of the situation.  My apologies for introducing confusion by my earlier carelessness.